# crontab - conditional task execution

Tags: linux, bash, cron

i'm trying to run following command from cron:

```
[[ -d some_folder_path ]] && [[ $(date +%u) -lt 6 ]] && touch ~/testOK
```

Unfortunately it's not working although when I run it outside the cron it works perfectly.

Kind request for help solving the issue.

Comment: have you tried to put it inside a script a run that script in cron?

Comment: yes, I did - it works but I need it to be done in crontab

Comment: cron defaults to `sh` so set your shell to `bash` if the `sh` in your system points to something else and not `bash`, or don't use `[[ ]]`, also the `%` gets interpreted by cron, escape it.

Comment: the shell is set to bash by SHELL=/bin/bash

Should I escape the % by adding the \ sign ?

Comment: @Jetchisel, thanks escaping the % by \ worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you have to make sure that your SHELL variable is set to Bash.
crontab has special meaning for % so you have to escape it using "\"

so I tested your cronjob it should be like

```
* * * * * [[ -d /Users/mkhade/Downloads ]] && [[ $(date +\%u) -lt 6 ]] && touch ~/testOK
```